# How to convert non-homogeneous json to dictionary<string,string> in C#?

Tags: c#, json.net, converters

I'm working on a project where I want to convert json data to dictionary but the problem is that the json is non-homogeneous. I'm using newtonsoft.json

Here is the JSON:

```
[{
    '_type': 'StatsItem',
    'Noofpostcomments': 0,
    'URL': 'https: //www.website.com/',
    'posts': 1,
    'Brand': 'Halfords',
    'Likes': 24884,
    'movedTo': 'FB',
    'sharing': 0,
    'talked': 94,
    'following': '24757',
    'Date': '27-Mar-2018',
    'unpopular': 0,
    'ID': '2453'
},
{
    '_type': 'StatsItem',
    'qualify': 53,
    'URL': 'https: //www.website.com/',
    'post': 3,
    'Brand': 'Kwik',
    'Likes': 32339,
    'movedTo': 'FB',
    'share': 128,
    'talk': 542,
    'followers': '31824',
    'Date': '27-Mar-2018',
    'bands': 240,
    'ID': '2453'
},
{
    '_type': 'StatsItem',
    'luck': 0,
    'URL': 'https: //www.website.com/',
    'bites': 0,
    'Brand': 'SEAT',
    'likes': 5329114,
    'movedTo': 'FB',
    'shares': 0,
    'talking': 552,
    'Followers': '5300000',
    'Date': '27-Mar-2018',
    'bands': 0,
    'ID': '2453'
},
{
    '_type': 'StatsItem',
    'spoofs': 1,
    'URL': 'https: //www.website.com/',
    'security': 1,
    'Brand': 'Honda',
    'fixes': 184065,
    'movedTo': 'FB',
    'shares': 15,
    'chat': 4251,
    'follow': null,
    'Date': '27-Mar-2018',
    'discussed': 102,
    'ID': '2453'
}]
```

Here is the code:

```
Dictionary<string, string> columnDictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(jsonString);
```

also tried

```
JObject result = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
```

It's giving exception

> An unhandled exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
>
> Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
>
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
>
> Path '', line 1, position 1.

Where have I gone wrong and what's the solution?

Comment: The problem is that's a Dictionary inside an Array.

Comment: i need key value pair or dictionary

Comment: @skhurams what you need is irrelevant.  The JSON is an array of object.  So at the very least your code needs to be a collection of Dictionary

Comment: can you convert it to array so that i might get key and value

Comment: The error message you posted in your question tells you exactly what the problem is.  Change your deserializiation into a _collection_ (List, Array, etc) of `Dictionary<string, string>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse that as an Array (or List) of dictionaries: `List<Dictionary<string, object>>`

```
var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, object>>>(jsonData);

foreach(var item in list)
{
    foreach(KeyValuePair<string, object> keyVal in item)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{keyVal.Key}: {keyVal.Value?.ToString()}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

> string responseString = @"**[**

The json describes an array of something, rather than a dictionary of something. Try deserialising to an array of Object first, then inspect what you get in the debugger to see if you can refine it to a more specific type object.

Also, it's heresy, but you could also use System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer from System.Web.Extensions, it's a lot older and dumber and can help deserialise 'unknown typed json'

Comment: Its not heresy if [Microsoft _explicitly_ tells you not to use it for JSON serializing/deserializing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx).  Also, you have posted no JSON in your answer just a weird blank variable that wont compile.

Comment: _I know_ what a JSON array looks like but OP _clearly_ does not.  Why make it confusing with a C# variable that does not compile.  It makes no sense contextually.  Use your words and describe the characteristics of an array so OP can learn

Comment: Hm, I could maybe turn the code into some kinda quote and bolden the [, otherwise I'm happy with it.

Comment: If you are happy with it, don't let me stop you.  Just trying to help you have a _better_ answer.  I would still **strongly** suggest you not perpetuate the `JavascriptSerializer` class because, as my link shows, Microsoft does not suggest using it anymore.

Comment: Hehe, till it's illegal to use, I'll remember it exists :D